# Does this deceptively simple nonlinear recurrence relation have a closed form solution?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, recurrences, difference-equations

Given the base case $a_0 = 1$, does $a_n = a_{n-1} + \frac{1}{\left\lfloor{a_{n-1}}\right \rfloor}$ have a closed form solution? The sequence itself is divergent and simply goes {$1, 2, 2+\frac{1}{2}, 3, 3+\frac{1}{3}, 3+\frac{2}{3}, 4, 4+\frac{1}{4}, 4+\frac{2}{4}, 4+\frac{3}{4}, . . .$} and so forth. It seems like it should be easy but I can't seem to find a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: I will point out that the tag (discrete-mathematics) is deprecated on MathOverflow, see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/discrete-mathematics/info). Moreover, the question is also missing [top-level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1457/why-are-mo-tags-formatted-as-they-are). Since I am not really sure about a suitable choice of tags for this question, I'll leave retagging to more experienced users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sequence $a_n$ for $n\geq 1$ has the following formula:
$$a_n=\left\lfloor \sqrt{2n}+\tfrac{1}{2}\right\rfloor +\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{8 n-7}+1\right)\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{8 n-7}+1\right)\right\rfloor ^2 +2 n}{2 \left\lfloor \sqrt{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor }.$$
Here is the [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BFloor%5B1%2F2+%2B+Sqrt%5B2%5D+Sqrt%5Bn%5D%5D+%2B+(++2+n+%2B+Floor%5B1%2F2+(1+%2B+Sqrt%5B-7+%2B+8+n%5D)%5D+-++++Floor%5B1%2F2+(1+%2B+Sqrt%5B-7+%2B+8+n%5D)%5D%5E2)%2F(2+Floor%5B1%2F2+%2B+Sqrt%5B2%5D+Sqrt%5Bn%5D%5D),%7Bn,1,15%7D%5D) link to check it.

It is related to [OEIS A002024](https://oeis.org/A002024) and [OEIS A002262.](https://oeis.org/A002262)

Comment: Great! Thanks, Carlo. Looking at that, I would have never have found that on my own. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A similar, possibly simpler closed form is the following: set $$b_n=\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}{2}\right\rfloor,$$
then $$a_n=\frac{b_n+1}{2}+\frac{n-1}{b_n}.$$
It is not hard to derive this from the observation that whenever $n-1$ is a triangular number $k(k-1)/2$, one has $a_n=k$.

Comment: it does not quite seem to work: I find from your formula $1,2,2,\frac{5}{2},3,3,\frac{10}{3},\frac{11}{3},4,4,\frac{17}{4},\frac{9}{2},\frac{19}{4},5,5,...$, so there is this repetition of the integers which should not be there... --- here is the [Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B(Floor%5B(-1+%2B+Sqrt%5B1+%2B+8*n%5D)%2F2%5D+-+1)%2F2+%2B++++n%2FFloor%5B(-1+%2B+Sqrt%5B1+%2B+8*n%5D)%2F2%5D,+%7Bn,+1,+15%7D%5D) --- did I make a mistake?

Comment: No, I did... Thanks! I had done everything in my mind and forgot to check

Comment: yes, the corrected formula now works as intended: [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B(Floor%5B(1+%2B+Sqrt%5B-7+%2B+8*n%5D)%2F2%5D+%2B1)%2F2+%2B++++(n-1)%2FFloor%5B(1+%2B+Sqrt%5B-7+%2B+8*n%5D)%2F2%5D,+%7Bn,+1,+15%7D%5D)

Comment: Actually the other night, I found Ale's simpler form as well only with $b_n = \left \lfloor{\sqrt{2n}+\frac{1}{2}}\right \rfloor$ instead. Apparently  $\left \lfloor{\frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}{2}}\right \rfloor =  \left \lfloor{\sqrt{2n}+\frac{1}{2}}\right \rfloor$.

Answer (score 3):

I have decided to call this sequence $\Theta_n$ for the triangular-harmonic number sequence because it clearly has properties related to both triangular and harmonic numbers.

I had been studying it by using the recursive definition $$\Theta_0 = 1\mid\Theta_n = \Theta_{n-1} + \frac{1}{\lfloor\Theta_{n-1}\rfloor}$$
The simplest closed form of the sequence is
$$\Theta_n = \frac{T_n^{-1}}{2} + \frac{n}{T_n^{-1}} + \frac{1}{2} \mid n\geq1$$ with $$T_n^{-1}=\lfloor\sqrt{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor$$ being the inverse triangular number function. I have been researching its many fascinating properties.